# Export Babylon.js as a native Oculus application

Tags: babylonjs, webxr, oculusquest

I'm implemented a WebXR app using Babylon.js.
To run it on my Oculus Quest 2, I'm using the Oculus browser.
Can I save it as a native Oculus application?

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to convert, or wrap, a WebXR app in to a native app as of early 2022.

The [exokit](https://github.com/exokitxr/exokit) project might be of interest, however, it has not been active recently.

More interesting is [BabylonNative](https://github.com/BabylonJS/BabylonNative) which is under heavy development. However, I don't believe it works on Oculus/Meta Quest devices yet (as of early 2022). (More [here](https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/oculus-app-for-quest-rift/22877/4).)

What is perhaps the best option *if* you don't need any actual native integration, is that Oculus/Meta Quest is starting to support **Progressive Web Apps (PWAs)** as of early 2022. *If* done correctly and eventually implemented as advertised by Meta, it's unlikely most users would know the difference between a native app and PWA in actual usage. And even though most PWA examples are currently 2D in nature, Meta has said that PWAs will have full WebXR support. More info:

- https://developer.oculus.com/pwa/
- https://web.dev/pwas-on-oculus-2/